# Python-jira get json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, jira

I'm trying to get **json** from jira api. For this I use [jira package](http://jira.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for python. 
It is good for getting project and issue info. But I don't know what to do if I need to **get json** from url like this:

> /jira/rest/structure/1.0/structure.json

Here is my server-side code:

```
from jira.client import JIRA

jira_options = {'server': 'https://bits.example.com/jira'}

try:
    jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,
                basic_auth=('user', 'pass'))
    project =  jira.project('CTT')
    print project
    print(project.lead.displayName)
except Exception, e:
    print e.args[0]
    print "Failed to connect to JIRA"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are requesting a resource which isn't available in the Python API.

You will want to make use of the requests library.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://bits.example.com/jira/rest/structure/1.0/structure.json',
    auth=('user', 'pass'))

json = response.json()
```

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: you can access the underlying JSON representation via the `raw` property.
E.g.:

```
jira = jira.JIRA(<jira server address>, basic_auth=(<username>, <password>))
issue = jira.issue('PROJ-1234')
print(issue.raw)
```

Longer answer:
https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/blob/develop/jira/resources.py

JIRA issues and other resources are subclasses of the Resource class (see file above).
One common property is `raw`, which as far as I can tell stores the original JSON data obtained from the JIRA REST API call.

Comment: Care to elaborate on why the -1?